# Using a list of word in findAssocs() in the tm R package

Tags: r, text-mining

I have been working with the findAssocs()function from the tm package in R.  If I am using the function with a single word I don't have any problems and I can manually input a multiple words I would like to find associations to in the following format:

```
findAssoc(corpusname,"cat","dog","elephant",.75,.75,.75)
```

Again no problem with manually inputting the multiple terms.  I am trying to find the associations to lists of terms sometimes that might contact 30 or 40 words. I would like to us either a list or vector with findAssocs() instead of having to type out each word every time.  Any ideas how to do this?  I tried making a custom function but I still so new to R I did not have any luck.  Thanks.

Thanks for the help.  R has a pretty steep learning curve for a newbie.  I tried the first method that you suggested and get an the error "Error: is.character(terms) is not TRUE"  The code that I am using is:

```
 #data for associates list
wordAssocList<- read.csv("Word Assocs List.txt")
# change TRUE to FALSE if you have no column headings in the CSV
as.character(wordAssocList)
attributes(wordAssocList)
my_assocs <- findAssocs(tdm, wordAssocList, .01)
my_assocs
```

For the output I get the following:

> as.character(wordAssocList)
>   [1] "logical(0)"
>   attributes(wordAssocList)
>   $names
>   [1] "ÿþp"

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
integer(0)

> my_assocs <- findAssocs(tdm, wordAssocList, .01)
>   Error: is.character(terms) is not TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Vectors shouldn't be a problem. See following example.

```
library(tm)

data("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude)

words <- c("oil", "opec", "xyz")
corr <- c(0.7, 0.75, 0.1)

# returns a list
my_assocs <- findAssocs(tdm, words, corr)

# turns list into a list of named dataframes.
my_list <- lapply(my_assocs, function(x) data.frame(terms = names(x), cor = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

**edit:** With the new version of dplyr (0.43) you can create a useful dataframe for the dataframes in the list, showing you the name of the dataframe the information is coming from. Handy for visualizations and other investigations.

```
my_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(my_list, .id = "source")

Source: local data frame [28 x 3]

   source    terms   cor
    (chr)    (chr) (dbl)
1     oil     15.8  0.87
2     oil  clearly  0.80
3     oil     late  0.80
4     oil   trying  0.80
5     oil      who  0.80
6     oil   winter  0.80
7     oil analysts  0.79
8     oil     said  0.78
9     oil  meeting  0.77
10    oil    above  0.76
..    ...      ...   ...
```

You could even use a dataframe instead of 2 vectors, just replace words and corr with the corresponding columns in your dataframe. The advantage of this, is that you can read in a text-file (or excel) where you have your lists of words and correlations

Comment: That actually answers another question that I had about compiling the output from the findAssocs() function.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I really appreciate it R has a pretty good learning curve for a newbie.  I am trying the first method that you posted I get an error.  Here is the code that I am using.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  R has a pretty steep learning curve for a newbie.  I tried the first method that you suggested and get an the error "Error: is.character(terms) is not TRUE"

Comment: check `class(wordAssocList)` and `is.vector(wordAssocList)`. Because I tested and use this in multiple situations. Also your as.character(wordAssocList) is not assigned to anything. So it will transform your wordAssocList to character and then not do anything with it. You probably mean `wordAssocList <- as.character(wordAssocList)`.